# To strip first line of all dat files in a folder

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to strip first lines of all dat files in a folder to bulk insert into SQL server. i know how to strip the first line of a .dat file and bulk insert it into sql server but how do i pass all dat files into the stripping command. the below is the powershell script i use for a single file

```
$file = "\\fileserver\files\user.dat"

get-content $file |
select -Skip 1 |
set-content "$file-temp"
move "$file-temp" $file -Force
```

and can i call the powershell script in a Sql server query window? below is my bulk insert

```
bulk insert dbo.user
from '\\fileserver1\files\user.dat'
with
(
firstrow = 1,
fieldterminator = '|',
rowterminator = '\n'
)
```

go

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will amend your *dat* files

```
ls "\\fileserver\files\*.dat" | % { 
    $file = $_.FullName
    get-content $file | select -Skip 1 | set-content "$file-temp"
    move "$file-temp" $file -Force
}
```

You can find out about executing Powershell from SSMS: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/28/four-easy-ways-to-import-csv-files-to-sql-server-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: i do get an error. This is my full path \\fileserver\Medicare Group\Red Book\2014\Feb 27\Delimited Monthly\dppfv1p

Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Book\2014\Feb'.
At line:1 char:3
+ ls <<<<  \\fileserver\Medicare Group\Red Book\2014\Feb 27\Delimited Monthly\dppfv1p\*.dat | % { 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: i changed it to get-childitem "\\fileserver1\Medicare Group\Red Book\2014\Feb 27\Delimited Monthly\dppfv1p" | % { 
    $file = $_.FullName
    get-content $file | select -Skip 1 | set-content "$file-temp"
    move "$file-temp" $file -Force
} and it works.